# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, classcastexception, apache-storm, runtimeexception

While running a storm topology I am getting this error.The topology runs perfectly for 5mins without any error then it fails.I am using

```
Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS as 300 sec i.e 5mins.
```

This is my inputstream :

`{"_id":{"$oid":"556809dbe4b0ef41436f7515"},"body":{"ProductCount":NumberInt(1),"category":null,"correctedWord":"bbtp","field":null,"filter":{},"fromAutocomplete":false,"loggedIn":false,"pageNo":"1","pageSize":"64","percentageMatch":NumberInt(100),"searchTerm":"bbtp","sortOrder":null,"suggestedWords":[]},"envelope":{"IP":"115.115.115.98","actionType":"search","sessionId":"10536088910863418864","timestamp":{"$date":"2015-05-29T06:40:00.000Z"}}}`

**This is the complete error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long 
cannot be cast to java.lang.String at 
backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) at 
backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) at 
backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) at 
backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4722$fn__4734$fn__4781.invoke(executor.clj:748) at
backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__458.invoke(util.clj:463) at 
clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to 
java.lang.String at 
backtype.storm.tuple.TupleImpl.getString(TupleImpl.java:112) at 
com.inferlytics.InferlyticsStormConsumer.bolt.QueryNormalizer.execute(QueryNor
malizer.java:40) at 
backtype.storm.topology.BasicBoltExecutor.execute(BasicBoltExecutor.java:50) at 
backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4722$tuple_action_fn__4724.invoke(executor.clj:633) at 
backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4645.invoke(executor.clj:4
04) at 
backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1446.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) at 
backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:125) ... 6 more
```

**My topology :**

```
public class TopologyMain {
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(TopologyMain.class);
private static final String SPOUT_ID = "Feed-Emitter";

/**
 * @param args
 */
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws AlreadyAliveException
 * @throws InvalidTopologyException
 */
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws AlreadyAliveException
 * @throws InvalidTopologyException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException {

    int numSpoutExecutors = 1;
    LOG.info("This is SpoutConfig");
    KafkaSpout kspout = QueryCounter();
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    LOG.info("This is Set Spout");
    builder.setSpout(SPOUT_ID, kspout, numSpoutExecutors);

    LOG.info("This is Query-Normalizer bolt");
    builder.setBolt("Query-normalizer", new QueryNormalizer())
    .shuffleGrouping(SPOUT_ID);

    LOG.info("This is Query-ProductCount bolt");
    builder.setBolt("Query-ProductCount", new QueryProductCount(),1)
    .shuffleGrouping("Query-normalizer", "stream1");

    LOG.info("This is Query-SearchTerm bolt");
    builder.setBolt("Query-SearchTerm", new QuerySearchTermCount(),1)
    .shuffleGrouping("Query-normalizer", "stream2");

    LOG.info("This is tick-tuple bolt");
    builder.setBolt("Tick-Tuple", new TickTuple(),1)
    .shuffleGrouping("Query-normalizer", "stream3");

    /*
     * Storm Constants
     * */

    String NIMBUS_HOST = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.STORM_CONSTANTS_FILE,
            ApplicationConstants.NIMBUS_HOST );
    String NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.STORM_CONSTANTS_FILE,
            ApplicationConstants.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT );
    String TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.STORM_CONSTANTS_FILE,
            ApplicationConstants.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS );
    String STORM_JAR = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.STORM_CONSTANTS_FILE,
            ApplicationConstants.STORM_JAR );
    String SET_NUM_WORKERS = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.STORM_CONSTANTS_FILE,
            ApplicationConstants.SET_NUM_WORKERS );
    String SET_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.STORM_CONSTANTS_FILE,
            ApplicationConstants.SET_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING );
    final int setNumWorkers = Integer.parseInt(SET_NUM_WORKERS);
    final int setMaxSpoutPending = Integer.parseInt(SET_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING);
    final int nimbus_thirft_port = Integer.parseInt(NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT);
    final int topology_tick_tuple_freq_secs = Integer.parseInt(TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS);


    /*
     * Storm Configurations
     */

    LOG.trace("Setting Configuration");
    Config conf = new Config();
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, NIMBUS_HOST);
    conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_THRIFT_PORT, nimbus_thirft_port);
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, topology_tick_tuple_freq_secs);
    System.setProperty("storm.jar",STORM_JAR );
    conf.setNumWorkers(setNumWorkers);
    conf.setMaxSpoutPending(setMaxSpoutPending);


    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
        LOG.trace("Storm Topology Submitted On CLuster");
        StormSubmitter. submitTopology(args[0], conf, builder.createTopology());
    }

    else
    {   
        LOG.trace("Storm Topology Submitted On Local");
        cluster.submitTopology("Query", conf, builder.createTopology());
        Utils.sleep(10000);
        cluster.killTopology("Query");
        LOG.trace("This is ShutDown cluster");
        cluster.shutdown();
    }

        LOG.trace("Method: main finished.");
}


private static KafkaSpout QueryCounter() {

    //Build a kafka spout

    /*
     * Kafka Constants
     */

    final String topic = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.KAFKA_CONSTANTS_FILE,
            ApplicationConstants.TOPIC );

    String zkHostPort = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.KAFKA_CONSTANTS_FILE,
            ApplicationConstants.ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_STRING );



    String zkRoot = "/Feed-Emitter";
    String zkSpoutId = "Feed-Emitter-spout";
    ZkHosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts(zkHostPort);

    LOG.trace("This is Inside kafka spout ");
    SpoutConfig spoutCfg = new SpoutConfig(zkHosts, topic, zkRoot, zkSpoutId);
    spoutCfg.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutCfg);
    LOG.trace("Returning From kafka spout ");
    return kafkaSpout;

  }

}
```

**My QueryNormalizer Bolt :**

```
public class QueryNormalizer extends BaseBasicBolt {
/**
 * 
 */

private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(QueryNormalizer.class);
public void cleanup() {}

/**
 * The bolt will receive the line from the
 * feed file and process it to Normalize this line
 * 
 * The normalize will be put the terms in lower case
 * and split the line to get all terms. 
 */
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    LOG.trace("Method in QueryNormalizer: execute called.");
    String feed = input.getString(0);

    String searchTerm = null;
    String pageNo = null;
    boolean sortOrder = true;
    boolean category = true;
    boolean field = true;
    boolean filter = true;
    String pc = null;
    int ProductCount = 0;
    String timestamp = null;
    String year = null;
    String month = null;
    String day = null;
    String hour = null;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int dayOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);  
    int weekOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); 

    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject(feed);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {

        LOG.error( "Json Exception in Query Normalizer", e1 );

    }

    try {
           searchTerm = obj.getJSONObject("body").getString("correctedWord");

           pageNo = obj.getJSONObject("body").getString("pageNo");
           sortOrder = obj.getJSONObject("body").isNull("sortOrder");
           category = obj.getJSONObject("body").isNull("category");
           field = obj.getJSONObject("body").isNull("field");
           filter = obj.getJSONObject("body").getJSONObject("filter").isNull("filters");
           pc = obj.getJSONObject("body").getString("ProductCount").replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
           ProductCount = Integer.parseInt(pc);
           timestamp = (obj.getJSONObject("envelope").get("timestamp")).toString().substring(10,29);
           year = (obj.getJSONObject("envelope").get("timestamp")).toString().substring(10, 14);
           month = (obj.getJSONObject("envelope").get("timestamp")).toString().substring(15, 17);
           day = (obj.getJSONObject("envelope").get("timestamp")).toString().substring(18, 20);
           hour = (obj.getJSONObject("envelope").get("timestamp")).toString().substring(21, 23);
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        LOG.error( "Parsing Value Exception in Query Normalizer", e );

    }

    searchTerm = searchTerm.trim();

    //Condition to eliminate pagination
     if(!searchTerm.isEmpty()){
         if ((pageNo.equals("1")) && (sortOrder == true) && (category == true) && (field == true) && (filter == true)){
             searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

            System.out.println("In QueryProductCount execute: "+searchTerm+","+year+","+month+","+day+","+hour+","+dayOfYear+","+weekOfYear+","+ProductCount);
            System.out.println("Entire Json : "+feed);
            System.out.println("In QuerySearchCount execute : "+searchTerm+","+year+","+month+","+day+","+hour);

            LOG.trace("In QueryNormalizer execute : "+searchTerm+","+year+","+month+","+day+","+hour+","+dayOfYear+","+weekOfYear+","+ProductCount);
            LOG.trace("In QueryNormalizer execute : "+searchTerm+","+year+","+month+","+day+","+hour);

            collector.emit("stream1", new Values(searchTerm , year , month , day , hour , dayOfYear , weekOfYear , ProductCount ));
            collector.emit("stream2", new Values(searchTerm , year , month , day , hour ));
            collector.emit("stream3", new Values());

            }LOG.trace("Method in QueryNormalizer: execute finished.");
     }


    }



/**
 * The bolt will only emit the specified streams in collector
 */
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {

    declarer.declareStream("stream1", new Fields("searchTerm" ,"year" ,"month" ,"day" ,"hour" ,"dayOfYear" ,"weekOfYear" ,"ProductCount"));
    declarer.declareStream("stream2", new Fields("searchTerm" ,"year" ,"month" ,"day" ,"hour"));
    declarer.declareStream("stream3", new Fields());

}
}
```

In the **QueryNormalizer** class the error is shown at this line

`String feed = input.getString(0);`

```
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
LOG.trace("Method in QueryNormalizer: execute called.");
String feed = input.getString(0);

String searchTerm = null;
```

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to 
>       java.lang.String at 
>       backtype.storm.tuple.TupleImpl.getString(TupleImpl.java:112) at 
>       com.inferlytics.InferlyticsStormConsumer.bolt.QueryNormalizer.execute(QueryNor
>       malizer.java:40)

**EDIT :**

After removing `Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS` from the config the code works properly.But I have to implement Tick Tuple () . How to achieve it?

I guess there is some problem with my TickTuple class. Is this the right way to Implement it ?

**TickTuple**

```
public class TickTuple extends BaseBasicBolt {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(TickTuple.class);


private static final String KEYSPACE = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.CASSANDRA_CONSTANTS_FILE,
        ApplicationConstants.KEYSPACE );
private static final String MONGO_DB = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.MONGO_CONSTANTS_FILE,
        ApplicationConstants.MONGO_DBE );
private static final String TABLE_CASSANDRA_TOP_QUERY = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.CASSANDRA_CONSTANTS_FILE,
        ApplicationConstants.TABLE_CASSANDRA_TOP_QUERY );
private static final String MONGO_COLLECTION_E = FilePropertyManager.getProperty( ApplicationConstants.MONGO_CONSTANTS_FILE,
        ApplicationConstants.MONGO_COLLECTION_E );

public void cleanup() {

}


protected static boolean isTickTuple(Tuple tuple) {
    return tuple.getSourceComponent().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_COMPONENT_ID)
        && tuple.getSourceStreamId().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_TICK_STREAM_ID);
}


@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {}


@Override
public void execute(Tuple input, BasicOutputCollector collector) {


         try {
            if (isTickTuple(input)) {
                CassExport.cassExp(KEYSPACE, TABLE_CASSANDRA_TOP_QUERY, MONGO_DB, MONGO_COLLECTION_E);
                TruncateCassandraTable.truncateData(TABLE_CASSANDRA_TOP_QUERY);

                Log.trace("In Truncate");
                return;
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



}
}
```

Can Anyone please suggest the required changes in the code ?

Comment: Hey! Interesting question, however could you try to pinpoint the part of your code that you think is causing the problem? Providing us with a wall of code to sift through makes our jobs much more difficult. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that there is a "wrong" input tuple in your stream. Could this be? What tuples does your spout emit?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax This is my input stream
`{"_id":{"$oid":"556809dbe4b0ef41436f7515"},"body":{"ProductCount":NumberInt(1),"category":null,"correctedWord":"bbtp","field":null,"filter":{},"fromAutocomplete":false,"loggedIn":false,"pageNo":"1","pageSize":"64","percentageMatch":NumberInt(100),"searchTerm":"bbtp","sortOrder":null,"suggestedWords":[]},"envelope":{"IP":"115.115.115.98","actionType":"search","sessionId":"10536088910863418864","timestamp":{"$date":"2015-05-29T06:40:00.000Z"}}}`

Comment: I can't infer anything from this. Sorry. As @mc-emeror answered, the cast fails, so the first field seems to be of type Long rather than String. Are you sure, that all input tuples lock alike (ie, have the same type for each field)?

Comment: Yeah all the inputs are of the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my TickTuple Bolt Implementation.I have added the 
`conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, topology_tick_tuple_freq_secs)`
In my main topology configuration.Instead it should be added in the bolt where TickTuple has be implemented.

I edited my TickTuple code , added this snippet and everything works fine.

```
 @Override
   public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
      // configure how often a tick tuple will be sent to our bolt
     Config conf = new Config();
     conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, topology_tick_tuple_freq_secs);
        return conf;
   }
```

This has to be added in the corresponding bolt instead of the main topology

Answer (score 2):

Now I understand: You have data tuples and tick tuples in the same input stream. Thus, for data tuples the first field is of type String, but for tick tuples it is of type Long. Thus, input.getString(0) runs in the ClassCastException for the first arriving tick tuple.

You need to update you bolt code like this:

```
Object field1 = input.getValue(0);
if (field1 instanceof Long) {
  Long tick = (Long)field1;
  // process tick tuple further
} else {
  String feed = (String)field1;
  // process data tuple as you did already
}
```

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/utils/TupleUtils.java for distinguish tick tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate between tick tuples and normal tuples within your execute method. Add this method to your bolt :

```
public boolean isTickTuple(Tuple tuple) {
    return tuple.getSourceComponent().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_COMPONENT_ID)
            && tuple.getSourceStreamId().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_TICK_STREAM_ID);
}
```

Now in execute, you can do

```
if(isTickTuple(tuple)){
  doSomethingPeriodic()
} else { 
  executeLikeBefore()
}
```